# I am unable to view created page using routing and controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new Laravel, and this is my first project, I got this project which already has some pages and I have to add an admin login page, so I created adminlogin.blade.php file in the resource folder, and make controller using command

```
php artisan make:controller AdminController
```

then in AdminController, I have created a function

```
public function viewAdminLogin() {
    return "Hello From admin login controller";//not working
    return view('adminlogin');//this one also not working, i have tried both return statement one by one.
}
```

Then in routes/web.php, I added this code

```
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/pricing', 'CalculatorController@index');

    Route::post('/quote', 'CalculatorController@quote');

    Route::get('/', 'Controller@index');

    // pages view
    Route::get('/howitworks', 'Controller@howitworks');

    Route::get('/US-Domestic-Shipping-Services', 'Controller@USDomesticShippingServices');

    Route::get('/International-Shipping-Services', 'Controller@InternationalShippingServices');

    Route::get('/Ship-Packages', 'Controller@ShipPackages');

    Route::get('/Ship-Envelopes', 'Controller@ShipEnvelopes');

    Route::get('/Student-Shipping', 'Controller@StudentShipping');

    Route::get('/about', 'Controller@About');

    Route::get('/FAQs', 'Controller@FAQs');

    Route::get('/Prohibited-Items', 'Controller@ProhibitedItems');

    Route::get('/Track-Shipment', 'Controller@TrackShipment');

    Route::get('/contact', 'Controller@Contact']);

    Route::get('/adminlogin', 'AdminController@viewAdminLogin');
```

I have also run these series of command after importing this project:

```
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
php artisan serve
```

after running http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminlogin it is returning a 404 page, Please help Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try after `php artisan route:clear`, if still not working then you have same  URI prefix with same method. Update your question with the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @EsTeAa didn't work

Comment: @EsTeAa I got this with list command GET|HEAD | adminlogin                      |      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@viewAdminLogin           | web

Comment: can you access `/FAQs` , `/about` ?

Comment: yes other pages are working

Comment: @EsTeAa clear commands have worked, i have restarted serve command after clearing all cache config and routes, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following clear commands:

```
//---Regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project
composer dump-autoload;
//---Remove Routes Cache
php artisan route:clear;
//---Flush the application cache
php artisan cache:clear;
//---Remove the configuration cache file
php artisan config:cache;
php artisan config:clear;
```

And after that restart your server

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: I think your clear commands worked, i have restarted serve command after clearing then it worked

Comment: remove controller.php and web.php code and just keep clear command and add note to restart server or serve command.. Then I will accept your answer, which will help others too.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the codes that you requested.

Comment: this problem is related with `route cache` only, not with composer, app cache, config cache

Comment: Yes, I got the answer, but it is a good idea to remove those caches also.

Answer (score 1):

If your route has been cached, then you need to clear the cache data :

```sh
php artisan route:clear
```

If you want to cache it, then simply run :

```sh
php artisan route:cache
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching) about route caching